# Is .xyz not available in China? Is accreditation is required for all new TLDs?

Tags: international, domain-name, china

Researching [abc.xyz](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/2300/would-googles-alphabet-inc-have-any-rights-to-alpha-bet), I've come across xyz.xyz and gen.xyz, with a prominent link from the latter to a page called ".xyz for China".

http://gen.xyz/china

> Thank you for your continued support of .xyz! With China being one of our biggest and most important markets, we wanted to inform you that we are in the process of becoming one of the few officially recognized domain extensions in China. We have submitted our application to the Chinese authorities, and will work with them in every way we can to ensure that we become accredited as soon as possible.
>
> If you are already an owner of .xyz domains, please be sure to renew them. We are still growing very quickly in China and would not want you to release the great domains names that you were able to secure during the first year of availability!

What does this mean?  Are the new generic TLDs not available in China?  What kind of special accreditation is required?